# Coloring of a table

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

We have a $5\times 5$ square table and $n$ different colours. We cut out $2\times 2$ squares from all vertex and remains $9$ unit squares. We will paint $9$ squares with $n$ colours. Some squares can be same colour. If the rotatings with respect to center of the table or the reftections of hortizonal symmetry axis, vertical symmetry axis, diagonals are indetical coloring, then how many are there distinc colouring (in terms of $n$) ?

For example $n=7$ and colours are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. We may not use the colors $6$, $7$. Some identical colorings:

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &  & 1 &  &  \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
 4& 2 & 2 & 2 & 5 \ \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
&  & 3 &  &   \\ \hline
\end{array} \to \text{symmetry w.r.t vertical axis}\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &  & 1 &  &  \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
 5& 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 \ \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
&  & 3 &  &   \\ \hline
\end{array}
$

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &  & 1 &  &  \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
 4& 2 & 2 & 2 & 5 \ \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
&  & 3 &  &   \\ \hline
\end{array} \to \text{rotate }90^\circ \text{ positive direction }\to
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &  & 5 &  &  \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
 1& 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 \ \\ \hline
 &  & 2 &  &   \\ \hline
&  & 4 &  &   \\ \hline
\end{array}
$

Comment: The symmetry here is dihedral $D_4.$ Factor the eight permutations to obtain the cycle index and evaluate at $n.$ Why is it we may not use six and seven?

Comment: I think that means simply that we are allowed to skip them.

Comment: If you want, all $9$ squares are same color. If you want you can use all colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the cycle index we get from the four rotations

$$a_1^9 + 2 a_1 a_4^2  + a_1 a_2^4$$

and from the horizontal / vertical reflections

$$2 a_1^5 a_2^2$$

and from the diagonal reflections:

$$2 a_1 a_2^4.$$

The cycle index becomes

$$Z(G) = \frac{1}{8}
\left(a_1^9 + 2 a_1 a_4^2 + 2 a_1^5 a_2^2  + 3 a_1 a_2^4\right).$$

This yields  for colorings with at  most $N$ colors the  form (here we
apply Burnside as  PET is not needed  and we simply note  that we have
$N$ choices for coloring a cycle,  where the color must be constant on
the cycle, e.g. $a_1^5 a_2^2$ has seven cycles and contributes $N^7$)

$$\frac{1}{8} ( N^9 + 2 N^3 + 2 N^7 + 3 N^5 )$$

which is the sequence

$$1, 110, 3105, 37264, 264875, 1332666, 5256475, 
\\ 17313920, 49645629, 127537750, \ldots$$

The following Perl script will compute  the first five entries of this
sequence.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#


MAIN : {
    my $mx = shift || 2;

    my @src =
        ([-2 ,0], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0],
         [0, -2], [0, -1], [0, 1], [0, 2]);

    my %coord2pos;

    for(my $pos = 0; $pos < 9; $pos++){
        $coord2pos{join('|', @{ $src[$pos]})} = $pos;
    }

    my @refl =
        (sub { - $_->[0], $_->[1]  },
         sub { $_->[0], - $_->[1]  },
         sub { $_->[1], $_->[0]  },
         sub { - $_->[1], - $_->[0] });

    my @res;

    for(my $n=1; $n <= $mx; $n++){
        my %orbits;

        for(my $idx = $n ** 9; 
            $idx < 2*($n ** 9); $idx++){
            my ($idxit, @digits) = ($idx);

            for(my $pos = 0; $pos < 9; $pos++){
                my $d = $idxit % $n;

                push @digits, $d;
                $idxit = ($idxit - $d) / $n;
            }

            my %orbit;

            my @data = @src;
            for(my $rot = 0; $rot < 4; $rot++){
                my @perm = 
                    map { $digits[$coord2pos{join('|', @$_)}] }
                @data;

                my $orbstr = join('-', @perm);
                $orbit{$orbstr} = 1;

                @data =
                    map { [ $_->[1], - $_->[0] ] }
                @data;
            }

            for(my $rfx = 0; $rfx < 4; $rfx++){
                my @perm = 
                    map { 
                        my @transf = &{ $refl[$rfx] }($_);
                        $digits[$coord2pos{join('|', @transf)}] }
                @src;

                my $orbstr = join('-', @perm);
                $orbit{$orbstr} = 1;
            }

            my $repr = (sort(keys %orbit))[0];
            $orbits{$repr} = 1;
        }

        push @res, scalar(keys %orbits);
    }

    print join(', ', @res);
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```

We can also answer the  question concerning colorings with exactly $N$
colors.   Call  the colorings  with  at  most  $N$ colors  $M_N.$  The
statistic for  an exact  number is  found by  inclusion-exclusion. The
nodes  $P$ of  the poset  that  we use  represent sets  of colors  and
include all configurations  that use some subset  thereof.  A coloring
with exactly $p$  colors is included in all nodes  that are a superset
of  these  colors.   With  the  weight   of  a  node  being  given  by
$(-1)^{N-|P|}$ we  get for $p\lt N$  the total weight by  choosing the
extra colors that join the $p$ colors

$$\sum_{q=0}^{N-p} {N-p\choose q} (-1)^{N-(p+q)} 
= (-1)^{N-p} \sum_{q=0}^{N-p} {N-p\choose q} (-1)^{q}
= 0.$$

On the other hand when $p=N$ these configurations are included only in
the node  $P$ that includes all  $N$ colors with weight  $(-1)^{N-N} =
1.$ These are precisely the right weights and we find

$$Q_N = \sum_{p=0}^N {N\choose p} (-1)^{N-p} M_p.$$

This yields the finite sequence

$$1,  108,  2778,  25500,   108510,  241920,  
\\ 292320,  181440,  45360,0,\ldots$$

which is finite because with nine available slots we can place at most
nine different colors.  The value  $108$ represents the two monochrome
colorings being  removed. With  nine colors all  orbits have  the same
size  namely eight  for the  eight permutations  and indeed  we obtain
$9!/8 = 45360.$

Comment: You're great! Thanks for your efforts.